# java plugin detection from javascript

Tags: java, jquery, javascript

From javascript how to detect the following plugin is installed on the system or not

http://www.java.com/en/download/

Answer (score 0):

[Here's the official java deployment toolkit script.](http://java.com/js/deployJava.js)

Check out the "versionCheck" method.

Doc:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html

Comment: Note that deployJava.txt is the non-minified version.